# Preventing server from adding trailing slash to image files

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I prevent server from redirecting from e.g. /images/img.png to /images/img.png/ ? I can use only htaccess.

Comment: This is not the default behavior for servers, so check what configuration is causing this in the first place.

Comment: I would love to, but it's not possible.

Comment: Also read up on the DirectorySlash directive.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the default behavior, so somewhere in your server's configuration you have something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+[^/]) [NC]
RewriteRule .  %1/  [L,R=301]
```

You can stop this by simply removing that rule from wherever it is in your global configuration.

If that's not possible; try turning off the rewrite engine for your site by adding `RewriteEngine Off` in your `.htaccess`.